# POST to a webhook?

Tags: http, discord, webhooks

I created a Discord webhook for my channel, now I am trying to send a POST request to it so my program automatically saves stuff to the channel. However when I send a post request it doesn't work. I added some screenshots for clarification

[image: OpenBullet, sends POST data]

[image: Discord Server]

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: I think the webhook content(post data) should be json.

Comment: It is json, {"message": "400: Bad Request", "code": 0}

Comment: Yes but the content what YOU send should also be json.

Comment: See https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook

Comment: I see, how'd I turn my post data into json? @dan1st

Comment: I have two variables called OrderID and TotalAmount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad Request means that your Request is invalid.

Discord only accepts JSON Request Bodies(See https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook)

As the docs describe, the body should look like that(it is minimalized, see the documentation, replace `message` with your message):

```
{
    "content": "message"
}
```

You can also send a file or an embed using this method.

You can also overwrite the default username/avatar of the webhook if you want to.

Comment: Thanks, this worked but the problem is now I get a very long response with { "Warnings": [], }

Comment: Is the message sent?

Comment: yes, just wondering how'd I get the { "Warnings": [], } away?

Comment: If the warnings array is empty(that thing between the `[]`, there are no warnings and anything is ok.

Comment: If you don't need the response, just don't use it