# Don't have access to post login payload

Tags: json, api

I am trying to send a login payload which is

```
{"username":"EMAIL","password":"PASSWORD","wnaMode":"modal"}
```

to https://www.zalando.nl/api/reef/login I am doing this so my program can login and get all my orders and put it in a spreadsheet automatically, however when I send the post request I get this back

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://failover.www.zalando.de/waf_deny_shop.html?" on this server.
Reference #18.9f633e17.1577580584.7b7612d
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of a bot-protection solution they use, it is working against login automations just like the one you wrote. Consider a scenario where someone is brute-forcing the password of a specific user or just tries to re-use credential dumps (AKA "credential stuffing") - this is why this defense mechanism is in place.

Comment: OP posted a snippet of OpenBullet (a well-known credential abuse tool) here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59514808/post-to-a-webhook/59515004
I guess he or she already knows why they are blocked ;)